# Cross-account setup of SES using TS cdk

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, amazon-ses

after I split my application into multiple environments I am unable to use SES in my app. Here is my AWS structure:
I have two AWS accounts under a single CDK app. Account ROOT is the root account containing the definition of SES resources using this class:

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as ses from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ses';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { ROOT_DOMAIN } from '../../iamphoto.constants';

export class SesStack extends cdk.Stack {
  public constructor(scope: Construct, props: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, SesStack.name, props);

    new ses.EmailIdentity(this, 'Identity', {
      identity: ses.Identity.domain(ROOT_DOMAIN)
    });
  }
}
```

another account is account DEV which is a development account that hosts dev environment and has a lambda service called "emailFunction" which is defined like this:

```js
  private getEmailsFunction(): lambdaNodeJs.NodejsFunction {
    const nodejsFunction = new lambdaNodeJs.NodejsFunction(this, 'emailsFunction', {
      functionName: 'emails-function',
      entry: `${projectRoot}/index.ts`,
      environment: {
        SES_REGION: 'eu-central-1',
        SES_EMAIL_FROM: this.envVariables.SES_EMAIL_FROM
      },
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
    });

    nodejsFunction.role?.addManagedPolicy(
      iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonSESFullAccess')
    );

    nodejsFunction.addPermission('InvokePermission', {
      principal: new iam.ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
      action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
    });

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'EmailsFunctionArn', {
      value: nodejsFunction.functionArn
    });

    return nodejsFunction;
  }
```

The problem is that my lambda function is not able to use AmazonSESFullAccess because the SES stack is implemented in the ROOT account. After all, the ROOT account has access to the domain (registered under route53).